# Is there a way to clear the cache without dropping tables?

Tags: drush

I am new to Drupal and realized that when we clear cache in Drupal 'drush cr'. It executes drop db commands.

This is a very big security issue in our company because granting drop privileges to a mysql user on a production server would be dangerous

What would be an alternate solution?

```
  In Connection.php line 686:
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 DROP command denied to user 'xxxxx'@'100.100.100.100' for table 'webprofiler': TRUNCATE {webprofiler}; Array()

  In Statement.php line 59:
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 DROP command denied to user 'xxxxx'@'100.100.100.100' for table 'webprofiler'
```

**Correction**

drush cr is **not** dropping tables. MySQL Truncate requires the DROP privilege as of MySQL 5.1.16. (Before 5.1.16, it requires the DELETE privilege).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.htm

So this means when drush cr is run you need a user with drop privileges.

Comment: What do you mean it executes DROP statements?

Comment: In Connection.php line 686:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 DROP command denied to user 'xxxxx'@'100.100.100.100' for table 'webprofiler': TRUNCATE {webprofiler}; Array
  (
  )


In Statement.php line 59:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 DROP command denied to user 'xxxxx'@'100.100.100.100' for table 'webprofiler'

Comment: It’s not doing DROP statements, it’s running TRUNCATE statements to flush tables. TRUNCATE requires the DROP permission. Clearing the cache does not delete/restore tables.

Comment: Thanks @kevin and Clive for pointing this out. Sucks that MySQL requires drop privilage for truncate to work.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html This is a big security issue for a production web deployment at least in my company.

Answer (score 3):

As Kevin correctly points out in the comments, the cache clear is issuing a `TRUNCATE` command rather than `DROP`, but `TRUNCATE` does require the `DROP` permission.

If you look at the manual installation method in the [install guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install/step-3-create-a-database#create-a-database-using-mysqlmariadb-commands), you'll see that `DROP` is one of the permissions that is granted as part of the setup process:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON databasename.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

That's followed shortly after by:

> **Note:** Unless the database user/host combination for your Drupal installation has all of the privileges listed above (except possibly CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, which is currently only used by Drupal core automated tests and some contributed modules), you will not be able to install or run Drupal.

So `DROP` is simply a required permission for Drupal to work.

Comment: Plus, most host setups have the database server isolated from external access without ssh, or at all. So this permission really isn’t an issue.

Comment: @Kevin you are right. even with isolated access having a db user with drop privileges if drush is in the server any hacker could run 'drush sql:drop' and so that makes it risky. thanks for providing some answers

Comment: Same thing if (heaven forbid) another remotely exploitable SQL vulnerability is found. It's a necessary evil unfortunately. Thinking about it more, it's not even just `TRUNCATE` that's required - the field API manages deleted data in tables that it needs to create and drop. So even if the permissions were separated, it's still not going to work.